# Why is my inbox answer count wrong?

Tags: bug

The picture should be self explanatory:

[image]

Comment: Note that this can't likely be "Caching", since (1) The issue persists 1 hour after the notification; (2) I didn't see any other answers, ever.

Comment: Could it have been deleted?

Comment: @rich I see deleted posts

Comment: Perhaps SFF.se is as bad at math as J.K. Rowling ;)

Comment: I saw this happen to me the other day on another SE site. I don't know what happened

Comment: Not the first time this has happened: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156246/stack-exchange-inbox-shows-incorrect-number-of-answers-for-a-question

Comment: Sorry. It had to be done. http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/500x/49576692.jpg

Comment: What about self-delete within the 5-minute grace period?  Does that keep the post?